# SimpleITK reading a slice of an image

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, simpleitk, numpy-memmap

Good day to all.

I happen to have a very large .mha file on my HDD (9.7 Gb) which is a 3D image of a brain. I know this image's shape and for the needs of a report, I would like to extract a slice of it, in order to get a 2D image that I can save as a .png.

The problem is that my 16 Gb RAM computer does not allow me to load the complete image and therefore I would like to know if there is a way to extract a 2D slice of this image without loading the whole image in RAM. For smaller images, I used `sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk.ReadImage(fileName))` and fed it to `pyplot.imshow()` but this implies to load the whole image which I want to avoid.

I thought for a time to use `numpy.memmap` in order to create a temporary `.npy` file in which I could store the whole array and then get a slice of it but I am having trouble allocating the array from image to it using `sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk.ReadImage(fileName))`.

Does anyone has an idea on how to do it?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SimpleITK you can read the header of an image, to get it's size information (and other meta-data).  Then you can tell the ImageFileReader to only read in a sub-section of the image.

The following example demonstrates how to do it:

https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/link_AdvancedImageReading_docs.html

The key is calling ImageFileReader's ReadImageInformation method first.  That gets all the header info.  Then calling SetExtractIndex and SetExtractSize to specify the sub-region to load before calling Execute to read the image.

Comment: Thank you. It got me some time to understance the code given in your link but I got to the essential of what I needed. Thank you again !

Comment: It's worth noting that reading subsections of images does not provide speed benefits when using `*.nrrd` files. I did some quick and dirty benchmarking with this, and the read time for an `*.nrrd` was ~1.2 seconds, regardless of how many slices I tried to read. This same problem did not appear on `*.mhd` and `*.nii.gz` files.